# Cordova onActivityResult is called immediately after startActivityForResult with RESULT_CANCELED

Tags: android, cordova

In the code below, when onActivityResult is called immediately with RESULT_CANCELED.

As suggested in other answers, I have added setActivityResultCallback just before startActivityForResult() and PluginResult#setKeepCallback(true);. But nothing is helping out.
Any suggestion?

```
 ....
  public boolean execute(String action, CordovaArgs args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

    this.callbackContext  = callbackContext;

    if (action.equals(ACTION_OPEN))
    {
        if(PermissionHelper.hasPermission(this, READ))
        {
            chooseFile();
        }
     }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

  public void chooseFile() {

    final CordovaPlugin plugin = (CordovaPlugin) this;
    Runnable worker = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Intent filePickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            filePickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            plugin.cordova.setActivityResultCallback(plugin);
            plugin.cordova.startActivityForResult(plugin, Intent.createChooser(filePickerIntent,"Choose file"), PICK_FILE_REQUEST);
        }
    };
    this.cordova.getThreadPool().execute(worker);
    PluginResult r = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT);
    r.setKeepCallback(true);
    callbackContext.sendPluginResult(r);

}

 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    Log.d(TAG,"Enter onActivityResult");

    if (requestCode == PICK_FILE_REQUEST) {

        Log.d(TAG,"requestCode == PICK_FILE_REQUEST");

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            Log.d(TAG,"Result Ok");

            Uri uri = data.getData();
            Log.d(TAG, uri.toString());

        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {

            Log.d(TAG,"Result canceled");

            callbackContext.error("OPERATION_CANCELLED");
            return;
        }

        this.callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR, "UNKNOWN_ERROR"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find the solution @dpaksoni?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue in one of my cordova application. I could not find the source of error but I resolved it by creating new project and installing all plugins again. It worked.

Comment: I tried the same and it worked. But still confused what was the problem in previous project.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the `setActivityResultCallback()` method!

If you check in [cordova source](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/08ab7d4b5951a88bcf63b592bfaec19eb12dbced/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaInterfaceImpl.java#L79), you will discover that `setActivityResultCallback` is an internal method with the purpose of calling `onActivityResult` with the `RESULT_CANCELED` parameter when a previous activity is still unfinished.

`setActivityResultCallback` should be a private method in Cordova code to avoid such bugs.